# wordpress wp_query with redux option is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

I want to have the ability to choose a category from theme option panel & it ll show all the posts from that exact particular category.

so I have setup my wp_query like this:

```
<?php
$featured_rcp= $redux_imd['featured_rcp'];
$catquery =  new WP_Query(array(
'category' => $featured_rcp,
'posts_per_page' => 1
)); 
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
 ?>
```

& my theme option panel code is:

```
'id' => 'featured_rcp',
'type' => 'select',
'data' => 'categories',
'multi' => true,
 'title'  => __('Recipe Category.', 'imd'),
'subtitle'   => __('Recipe Category for home page.', 'imd')
```

but it showing posts from all categories, not the one which I select from option panel. though posts per page is working fine. I'm not well versed in PHP, so please some one tell me where I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: have you verified that `$redux_imd['featured_rcp']` is not empty?

Comment: print it out before your loop.

Comment: no it is not empty, it returns: 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The category parameter of the WP_Query is wrong, it should be `cat` or `category_name`, depending on the type of the value.

Check out the [Category Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) of WP_Query and choose which one you need.

Comment: interesting, I've used both `cat` and `category_name` before, but didn't work. this time `cat` is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
global $redux_imd;

$featured_rcp = !empty($redux_imd['featured_rcp']) ? $redux_imd['featured_rcp'] : array();

if ( !empty($featured_rcp) ) :

    query_posts( array( 'cat' => $featured_rcp, 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );

    if (have_posts()) : 
         while (have_posts()) : the_post();
             the_title()
         endwhile;
    else :
        _e('No post found!');
    endif; 

endif;
```

Working for me.